# How to read data from servlet response in JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have one servlet which generates an XML file. After completion of execution this servlet redirects page to one of the JSP page. I want get XML (generated from servlet) in this JSP and do some processing on it. (I do not want to give that XML for downloading to the user, I want to read that XML in JSP).

Comment: Then change the code of the servlet so that it doesn't write to the response, but to an in-memory string passed as a request attribute to the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to the filter java file.**

```
static class MyHttpServletResponseWrapper 
  extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

  private StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(BUFFER_SIZE);

  public MyHttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
  }

  public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
    return new PrintWriter(sw);
  }

  public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  public String toString() {
    return sw.toString();
  }
}
```

**Use the follow code:**

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
MyHttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = 
  new MyHttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResponse);

chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

String content = wrapper.toString();
```

[***click to refer this site***](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-server-response.htm)